# Altium Designer flips all text notes

Tags: altium

When I open a project in Altium Designer 16, all text comments show as flipped 180 deg like so:

[image]

When I open the same project with Altium Viewer 09 all comments appear normal so I know it's definitely not the project.

I tried closing a project from Altium 16 without saving any changes and next time I open it there are already some unsaved changes to the project. This tells me Altium probably flips the comments on startup but then if I save the files and open them with the Viewer, all comments look normal.

Is there a setting to configure this or is it a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem any time I imported a project from PCAD. There is a setting in the DXP Schematic preferences called "Display Strings As Rotated" that is automatically checked in the newer versions of the software. I believe you just need to make sure this is unchecked before importing or opening any projects. This setting is found in the `DXP menu -> Preferences -> Schematic -> Graphical Editing` under the "Options" heading:

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear it! =)

Comment: However, you would be well served to keep "Display Strings As Rotated" checked, and fix the orientation of the strings.  If you don't, then this issue will continue to haunt you (and others) forever more.  Altium made the mistake of making the default 'off' for previous versions.  I understand it's a bit of a pain fixing this, but in reality it takes just minutes to find and fix all rotated bits with the inspector.  Strings should be displayed using the orientation information tied to them by the designer.  For imported SCH's, just expect to fix them.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Good point. In my imports I always fixed the orientation to 0 degrees. Unchecking the "Display Strings As Rotated" simply ignores the "Rotation" setting, but it would be much more reliable to use the SCH Inspector to select all text and set its orientation to 0 degrees.